# Why does my C++ application consume too much system resources and not respond?

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

I want search a string in a text file. I use CodeBlocks as IDE.

Here are my codes:

```
string strLineToRead;

ifstream ifFile;
ifFile.open("FileToRead.txt");

while(strLineToRead.find("blabla") == string::npos)
{
     getline(ifFile, strLineToRead);
}

ifFile.close();

return 0;
```

Comment: You should learn how to debug your code.

Comment: How will this program ever get out of the `while` loop, in the case where the file doesn't contain the string "blablah" ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains a `while` loop, it would cause a lot of resources if your condition is not meet, in this case, it is `strLineToRead.find("blabla") == string::npos`, if that happens, you will enter into an infinite loop. Consider change your condition to this `while(getline(ifFile, strLineToRead))`
You can also consider open the file with open mode to reduce the resource.

Answer (score 0):

[Below](https://onlinegdb.com/92t8E-d_1) is a working example/demo that shows how to find a given string inside a text file:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    
    std::string line, stringtobeSearched = "blabla";

    std::ifstream inFile("input.txt");
    
    
    if(inFile)
    {
        while(getline(inFile, line, '\n'))        
        {
            //std::cout<<line<<std::endl;
            //if the line read does not contain the string searched for 
            if(line.find(stringtobeSearched) == std::string::npos)
            {
               ; //do something here
            }
            //if the line read contains the string searched for then print string  found
            else 
            {
                std::cout<<"string found "<<std::endl;
            }
            
            
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"file could not be read"<<std::endl;
    }
    inFile.close();
    
    
   
    return 0;
}
```

**input.txt**

```
this is first line 
this is second blabla
third line is this 
blabla again found for second time
```

The output of the above program is as follows([here](https://onlinegdb.com/92t8E-d_1)):

```
string found 
string found
```

Comment: I think your code has errors. "!= string::npos" means "String is found.", "== string::npos" means "String is not found."

Comment: Yup, thanks for spotting the typo.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just made a typo. But I can't help myself, I like to code.
So… Here is my attempt:

```
auto infile = std::ifstream("./file.txt");

for (auto line = std::string(); std::getline(infile, line); ) {
  if (std::string::npos != line.find("blabla")) {
    std::puts("Found it.");
    return {};
  }
}

std::puts("Nope.");
```

[Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/6Yj3obnzr)